# Serverless.yml AWS Lambda in Windows 10: The symlinked folder is not in final package

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

My folder structure like this:

```
Root ---
common
    search
        elastic_client
            elastic_client.py
        elastic_delete
            elastic_delete.py
            requirements.txt
            elastic_client (symlink)
                ../elastic_client
function1
    elastic_delete (symlink)
        ../common/search/elastic_delete
    serverless.yml
        functions:
            elastic-delete:
                handler: elastic_delete.lambda_handler
                module: elastic_delete
                package:
                    include:
                        - elastic_delete/**
```

When I do "sls deploy", the elastic_client folder is not getting deployed/not in the final .zip file, that means the elastic_client.py is not getting packed. This issue is only in Windows 10. In Mac, I don't see this issue.

I created symlinks with the command mklink.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a windows machine, but typically the way I do this is packaging functionality of the framework. https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/google/guide/packaging/

At least for MacOS, I just include the directories I want (relative from where the `serverless.yml` files are, and they are included into the directory of the deployed package.

Hope that helps.